# How to send the file returned from a function over post in GatLing-Scala?

Tags: scala-gatling

```
def siteNameChange():File={

  for(line<-Source.fromFile("RecordedSimulation_0000_NewSiterequest2.txt").getLines())
    if(line.contains("siteUrl"))
        println(line)
 return new File("RecordedSimulation_0000_NewSiterequest2.txt")      
}


val scn = scenario("RecordedSimulation")
    .exec(http("request_0")
        .post(“/student/new”)
        .body(RawFileBodyPart(session=>siteNameChange())).asJSON)
```

Hello I am a newbie to Gatling, using it for performance testing. I have a function named siteNameChange() which returns a file after doing some modifications on the file.
This function I am calling in the scenario body to send the data.

But when I am running the script I am getting     scala:48:26: missing parameter type
            .body(RawFileBodyPart(session=>siteNameChange())).asJSON)

Can some one please suggest whats the best thing to do this here, how to get the function return the modified file and pass the file data over the post request

Answer (score 0):

`body` doesn't take a `BodyPart` (which is for multipart) parameter but a `Body` one.
You should be passing a `RawFileBody`.

Comment: oops yeah, you are correct, it is RawFileBody(), not RawFileBodyPart()

Comment: Please validate answer.

Comment: Thanks, but the answer is not exactly correct. Anyways I have found a way to do it.
The workaround is from the function siteNameChange() instead of returning a File, return the filename as a string.
Now, in the scenarios's Body(), RawFileBody() accepts the filename as a string, so that works.